# Function to check whether two int values are within a given range of each other

Tags: c

For example, take `int x = 30;` and `int y = 27;`. My program would call the function `bool CheckWithinRange(int x, int y, int range);` as `CheckWithinRange(x, y, 3)` or `CheckWithinRange(y, x, 3)` and it would return true.

**EDIT** Sorry, my bad, my question is simply: How can such a function be written?

Comment: Yes, but what is your question?

Comment: @PeterSmith Sorry, I didn't realise how unclear I was. Question edited.

Comment: Check the absolute value of the difference. I don't know C well enough to give you details.

Comment: What do you mean by 'digits'? Are `13` and `23` apart by 1 digit or 10 digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

bool CheckWithinRange(int x, int y, int range)
{
    if (abs(x-y) <= range)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 30;
    int y = 27;
    int range = 5;

    if (CheckWithinRange(x,y,range))
    {
        printf("X and Y are within 5 digits");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("X and Y are not within 5 digits.");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The [`abs()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/abs/?kw=abs) function from `stdlib` can be used to find the absolute difference between 2 numbers in C. Enjoy!

If you are worried about arithmetic overflow then @chqrlie's answer is what you are looking for.

Comment: You can make the `ChecWithinRange()` function even simpler by having `return abs(x - y) <= range;`

Comment: @bentank I know, but I did it this way on purpose :P. It can also be simplified further by removing the function entirely to lower the overhead (which was a tiny tiny tiny bit) and moved the check into the if statement in the main.

Comment: This function works for most cases, but not if `x-y` or `abs(x-y)` cause integer arithmetic overflow. `CheckWithinRange(INT_MIN, 1)` invokes undefined behaviour :(

Comment: @chqrlie True, this answer was for the sake of learning how to calculate the absolute difference between 2 numbers.

Comment: Yes, and mine is for showing how simple looking questions may contain hidden difficulties. The very kind that can and did cause a billion dollar rocket launch failure, although C was not used then, but Ada.

Answer (score 2):

This question is actually a little tricky to answer in the general case. If `x` or `y` can be very large or very far apart, `x-y` may overflow.  Here is a solution that solves the question for all `int` values of `x`, `y` and `range`:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool CheckWithinRange(int x, int y, int range) {
    if (range < 0)
        return false;
    if (x <= y)
        return x >= INT_MAX - range || x + range >= y;
    else
        return y >= INT_MAX - range || y + range >= x;
}
```